# What does this definition of polynomials mean?

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-geometry

Let Rn be a Euclidian space. P(x) = a<x, x>  + <b, x>  + c of
x ∈ Rn where the leading coefficient a and the constant term c are real numbers and b ∈ Rn
is called a quadratic polynomial. If a is equal to one, then P is called a monic quadratic
polynomial.

Could someone explain what this terminology especially the brackets <> means?

Comment: The bracket is called the inner product.

Comment: Also sometimes called the dot product.

Comment: In closed form, this is: $$p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n(ax_i^2+b_ix_i) +c.$$

Comment: Why are the coefficients of the square terms not changing?